# Find all numbers in a range for which x is a factor?

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I was wondering if I can use loop, to find, for example, the smallest or largest number between 10000 and 20000 that is divisible by some number, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single loop, like so

```r
out <- c()

for(i in 10000:20000){
  if(i %% 1234 == 0) { out <- c(out, i) }
}

 out
[1] 11106 12340 13574 14808 16042 17276 18510 19744
```

Comment: Thanks @stevec. Is there a way to do the largest and smallest differently? i.e, what would be the way to get the output of "out" spell out only the largest?

Comment: @ShaneMurphy `max(out`, `min(out)`

Answer (score 0):

What is your plan with that loop? If you just want the smallest number divisible by 1234, than why use a loop instead of `min(c(10000:20000)[which(10000:20000 %% 1234 == 0)])`?

Also note that you could also use `while()` when you want a loop going on until some condition is met:

```
i <- 10000
while(i < 20000 & !i %% 1234 == 0){
   i <- i + 1
}

i
```

This will give you either the smallest number divisible by 1234 or 20000, in case there is no such number. Exchange the starting number and subtract instead of adding in order to run it backwards and get the largest number.